# Cannot respond to a POST request from a HTML Form

Tags: html, css, ajax, express, bootstrap-4

I am new to the Express and Bootstrap. Today, I was trying to create a form for logging in. The form will trigger a POST request to the server and I want to send a new HTML page whenever a POST request is sent but there is always a problem "The page isn't working".

This is my HTML form:

```
<section class="h-100">
<div class="container h-100" style="margin-top: 50px; ">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center h-100" >
<div class="card-wrapper">
<div class="card fat">
<div class="card-body">
<h3 class="card-title">Login</h3>
<form method="POST" class="my-login-validation" novalidate="">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">E-Mail Address</label>
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" required autofocus>
<div class="invalid-feedback">
Email is invalid
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password
</a>
</label>
<a href="forgot.html" style="float: right">
Forgot Password?
</a>
<input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required data-eye>
<div class="invalid-feedback">
Password is required
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group m-0">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
Login
</button>
</div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

And this is my Express where I try to respond the form with a new html page:

```
router.post("/index.html", function(req, res, next){
   res.send(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang='en'>
  <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Practical Excercise 3 - Part 3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> Thanh Toan </p>
  </body>
  </html>
  `);
});
```

When a login button in HTML is clicked, a POST request is sent. When the server receive a POST request, I want to send back a new HTML page but a problem occur. Can anyone tell me where the problem is?
Thanks you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

REMEMBER TO TURN THE SERVER ON  `npm start`

Have a good day!